# IOS Count current streak of days

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a day streak counter using UserDefaults and Core Data.

The idea is that a number will be added unto by 1 every separate day an action is performed-- this will be the streak number.
If this action wasn't performed for 24 hours, the number would reset to zero.

I have a function to set the end of the streak:

```
 // set date time to the end of the day so the user has 24hrs to add to the streak
 func changeDateTime(userDate: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    let currentCalendar = NSCalendar.current
    let year = Int(currentCalendar.component(NSCalendar.Unit.Year, fromDate: 
    userDate))
    let month = Int(currentCalendar.component(NSCalendar.Unit.Month, fromDate: 
    userDate))
    let day = Int(currentCalendar.component(NSCalendar.Unit.Day, fromDate: userDate))

    dateComponents.year = year
    dateComponents.month = month
    dateComponents.day = day
    dateComponents.hour = 23
    dateComponents.minute = 59
    dateComponents.second = 59

    guard let returnDate = currentCalendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents) else {
        return userDate
    }
    return returnDate
 }
```

It is returning the following Errors:

> 'NSDate' is not implicitly convertible to 'Date'; did you mean to use
> 'as' to     explicitly convert?
>
> Cannot convert value of type 'NSCalendar.Unit' to expected argument
> type     'Calendar.Component'

When using the suggested corrections I only get more errors with no suggested corrections. I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way to express this

The full Code is:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!

var lastStreakEndDate: NSDate!
var streakTotal: Int!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // checks for object if nil creates one (used for first run)
    if userDefaults.object(forKey: "lastStreakEndDate") == nil {
        userDefaults.set(NSDate(), forKey: "lastStreakEndDate")
    }

    lastStreakEndDate = (userDefaults.object(forKey: "lastStreakEndDate") as! NSDate)

    streakTotal = calculateStreak(lastDate: lastStreakEndDate)
}





// fetches dates since last streak
func fetchLatestDates(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, lastDate: NSDate) -> [NSDate] {
    var dates = [NSDate]()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "streakCount")
    let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "date < %@", lastDate)

    fetchRequest.predicate = datePredicate

    do {
        let result = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let allDates = result as! [NSDate]
        if allDates.count > 0 {
            for date in allDates {
                dates.append(date)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
    return dates
}


// set date time to the end of the day so the user has 24hrs to add to the streak
func changeDateTime(userDate: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    let currentCalendar = NSCalendar.current
    let year = Int(currentCalendar.component(NSCalendar.Unit.Year, fromDate: userDate))
    let month = Int(currentCalendar.component(NSCalendar.Unit.Month, fromDate: userDate))
    let day = Int(currentCalendar.component(NSCalendar.Unit.Day, fromDate: userDate))

    dateComponents.year = year
    dateComponents.month = month
    dateComponents.day = day
    dateComponents.hour = 23
    dateComponents.minute = 59
    dateComponents.second = 59

    guard let returnDate = currentCalendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents) else {
        return userDate
    }
    return returnDate
}





// adds a day to the date
func addDay(today: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    let tomorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: today, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))

    return tomorrow!
}



// this method returns the total of the streak and sets the ending date of the last streak
func calculateStreak(lastDate: NSDate) -> Int {
    let dateList = fetchLatestDates(moc: moc, lastDate: lastDate)
    let compareDate = changeDateTime(userDate: lastDate)
    var streakDateList = [NSDate]()
    var tomorrow = addDay(today: compareDate)

    for date in dateList {
        changeDateTime(userDate: date)
        if date == tomorrow {
           streakDateList.append(date)
        }
        tomorrow = addDay(today: tomorrow)
    }

    userDefaults.set(streakDateList.last, forKey: "lastStreakEndDate")
    return streakDateList.count
}
```

Any Help is Appreciated

Comment: Your `changeDateTime` method can be written in one line. `return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59, of: userDate)`. By the way avoid `NS...` classes if there are native Swift counterparts. You can even declare dates in Core Data as Swift `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
// set date time to the end of the day so the user has 24hrs to add to the streak
func changeDateTime(userDate: Date) -> Date {
   var dateComponents = DateComponents()
   let currentCalendar = Calendar.current
    let year = Int(currentCalendar.component(.year, from:
   userDate))
   let month = Int(currentCalendar.component(.month, from:
   userDate))
   let day = Int(currentCalendar.component(.day, from: userDate))

   dateComponents.year = year
   dateComponents.month = month
   dateComponents.day = day
   dateComponents.hour = 23
   dateComponents.minute = 59
   dateComponents.second = 59

    guard let returnDate = currentCalendar.date(from:dateComponents) else {
       return userDate
   }
   return returnDate
}
```

**OR shortly**

```
// set date time to the end of the day so the user has 24hrs to add to the streak
func changeDateTime(userDate: Date) -> Date {
   var dateComponents = DateComponents()
   let currentCalendar = Calendar.current
   let res = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day],from:userDate)
    dateComponents.year = res.year
    dateComponents.month = res.month
    dateComponents.day = res.day
    dateComponents.hour = 23
    dateComponents.minute = 59
    dateComponents.second = 59 
    guard let returnDate = currentCalendar.date(from:dateComponents) else {
       return userDate
   }
   return returnDate
}
```